# how to assign values from Json file to Javascript array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, typeahead.js

to populate the countries list in my [typeahead search](http://www.runningcoder.org/jquerytypeahead/documentation/) I am declaring manually.

```
var data = [
    {
        "id": "Austria",
        "continent": "Europe" 
    }, 
         ...
    { 
        "id": "USA",
        "continent": "America" 
    }
];
```

I want the array `data` will get data from an external json file. Let's say my `countries.json` file contains this data

```
[
    {
        "id": "Austria",
        "continent": "Europe"
    }, 
    {
        "id": "France",
        "continent": "Europe"
    }, 
    {
        "id": "Japan",
        "continent": "Asia"
    }, 
    {
        "id": "USA",
        "continent": "America"
    }
]
```

I used `getJSON` To load the json data in my array `data`

```
var data = [];
$.getJSON( "js/countries.json", function(json){
  data = json;
  console.log(data);
});
```

The console shows me that `data` contains the values I need but in the rest of my code where I am using `data` as source it's not working. When I load data from Json file, i don't have any country shown in the search input.

Any suggestions please what I am missing ? Thank you.

```js
var data = [{
  "id": "Austria",
  "continent": "Europe"
}, {
  "id": "France",
  "continent": "Europe"
}, {
  "id": "Japan",
  "continent": "Asia"
}, {
  "id": "USA",
  "continent": "America"
}];


typeof $.typeahead === 'function' && $.typeahead({
  input: ".js-typeahead-input",
  minLength: 0,
  hint: true,
  searchOnFocus: true,

  group: {
    key: "continent",
    template: function(item) {
      var continent = item.continent;
      return continent;
    }
  },
  emptyTemplate: 'no result for {{query}}',
  groupOrder: ["Europe", "Asia", "America"],
  display: ["id"],
  correlativeTemplate: true,
  dropdownFilter: [{
    key: 'continent',
    template: '<strong>{{continent}}</strong> continent',
    all: 'All Countries'
  }],
  multiselect: {
    matchOn: ["id"],
    data: function() {
      var deferred = $.Deferred();
      return deferred;
    }
  },

  template: '<span>' +
    '<span class="id">{{id}}</span>' +
    '</span>',
  source: {
    groupName: {
      data: data
    }
  },
  debug: true
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-typeahead/2.10.6/jquery.typeahead.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-typeahead/2.10.6/jquery.typeahead.js"></script>

<div class="typeahead__container">
  <div class="typeahead__field">
    <span class="typeahead__query">
                <input class="js-typeahead-input"
                       name="q"
                       type="search"
                       autofocus
                       autocomplete="on">
            </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: where are you calling the data variable you created?

Comment: @AndreaPeekatchuFollack  here in this part;  source: { groupName: { data: data}  }

Comment: you can always use a js file exporting a variable called data with your object

Comment: Please include success handler in `getjson` then parse the data to JSON and  do remaining task in success handler

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
data = JSON.parse(json);
```

The request will get text and you need to parse that text into a JavaScript object. See how if I convert the object in your snippet to a string it needs to be parsed. Try

```
console.log(typeof json)
```

and you will see it is a string, not an array.

```js
var data = JSON.parse(`[{
  "id": "Austria",
  "continent": "Europe"
}, {
  "id": "France",
  "continent": "Europe"
}, {
  "id": "Japan",
  "continent": "Asia"
}, {
  "id": "USA",
  "continent": "America"
}]`);


typeof $.typeahead === 'function' && $.typeahead({
  input: ".js-typeahead-input",
  minLength: 0,
  hint: true,
  searchOnFocus: true,

  group: {
    key: "continent",
    template: function(item) {
      var continent = item.continent;
      return continent;
    }
  },
  emptyTemplate: 'no result for {{query}}',
  groupOrder: ["Europe", "Asia", "America"],
  display: ["id"],
  correlativeTemplate: true,
  dropdownFilter: [{
    key: 'continent',
    template: '<strong>{{continent}}</strong> continent',
    all: 'All Countries'
  }],
  multiselect: {
    matchOn: ["id"],
    data: function() {
      var deferred = $.Deferred();
      return deferred;
    }
  },

  template: '<span>' +
    '<span class="id">{{id}}</span>' +
    '</span>',
  source: {
    groupName: {
      data: data
    }
  },
  debug: true
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-typeahead/2.10.6/jquery.typeahead.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-typeahead/2.10.6/jquery.typeahead.js"></script>

<div class="typeahead__container">
  <div class="typeahead__field">
    <span class="typeahead__query">
                <input class="js-typeahead-input"
                       name="q"
                       type="search"
                       autofocus
                       autocomplete="on">
            </span>
  </div>
</div>
```